# AndroidStudio says Could not identify launch activity: Default Activity not found"

Tags: android-studio

The app works as expected.  - it is only the IDE that apparently fail to upload/run it.

> 05/15 14:37:53: Launching 'app' on Google Glass 1. Install
> successfully finished in 1 s 954 ms. Could not identify launch
> activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity

My manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="no.ut.glassbrowser"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity
            android:immersive="true"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.glass.action.VOICE_TRIGGER" />
            </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.glass.VoiceTrigger"
                android:resource="@xml/voice_trigger" />
            
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What Am I missing?

Comment: You should set your launcher activity in your manifest file. In intent filter you should write
`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

Comment: If you have upgraded your Android Studio, then do so:
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 0):

In your "intent-filter" tag you should have this code

```
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```